Shelly real time monitory the current energy
How can I monitor the current energy consumption with a script? Do I need to set up any events, etc.? I have the Shelly Pro 4PM and I want to switch off certain circuits when the electrical load is too high, and then switch them back on when the load decreases.
Shelly.addEventHandler(function(apower_change,ud){
    let consumption = 0;
    for(let i = 0;i < 4; i++) {
       Shelly.call("Switch.GetStatus",{id: i},
          function(result,error_code,error_message,ud){
            print(result.apower);
            consumption = consumption + result.apower
          },null);
    };
     print(consumption);
  },null
);

Cheers
Imox

Uncaught Error: Too many calls in progress 08:40:32 at line 7 col 17
08:40:32 },null); 08:40:32 ^ 08:40:32 in function called from system

